# Preserving good semantics with repetitive content

Tags: html, seo, accessibility, semantic-ui

Say I'm building a typical document editor:

[image: Typical document-editing interface. It's made of two vertical panels. The left panel contains various text fields. The right panel shows a preview of the document. The preview content reflects the values of the fields.]

Where the preview (in red) is an up-to-date, formatted vue of the form's data.

The preview element contains semantic elements (e.g. `h1`, `h2`, `main`, `header`, etc.). It's kind of a document in itself, which does make sense, conceptually. But this makes the structure of the *real* document quite confusing for crawlers and screen readers. There might be, for instance, two `h1` or `main` elements. I'm looking for a way to avoid that.

Plus, there's the problem of repetitive content (see image).

For the accessibility part of the problem, I could just add an `aria-hidden="true"` attribute to the preview element. In fact, visually-impaired people don't need the preview, it's just redundancy to them, they just need the form.

But for crawlers, here are my options:

- Don't use semantic elements inside the preview element, use `div`s instead ().
- Host the preview at an other URL and insert it via an `iframe` (that's what I'm doing right now, but it seems hacky to me).
- Leave it like that, crawlers don't care.

Any idea/resource/suggestion?

Comment: Why would you be concerned with SEO for such transient content as the editor preview? I think option 1 makes most sense.

Comment: You have a point, but it's not just SEO. Having semantic elements makes my CSS better factored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your preview area is clearly indicated for assistive technology, it's perfectly fine to have redundant information.  If you have an `<iframe>`, make sure there's a `title` attribute on it.

```
<iframe title="preview area"...>
```

However, you might have [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) issues with multiple structure elements.

For example, HTML only allows one [`<main>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) element:

> A document must not have more than one `main` element that does not have the `hidden` attribute specified.

You **can** have multiple [`<header>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-header-element) elements but a `<header>` has a default role of [banner](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#banner) and the banner role says:

> Within any document or application, the author SHOULD mark no more than one element with the banner role.

The key here is "[should](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119#section-3)", meaning it's a strong recommendation but not required.  You can also get away with multiple banner roles if your preview section has [`role="document"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#document).

I would recommend **not** using non-semantic elements (`div`) because an assistive technology user might want to check the actual semantic structure of what's generated, although I suppose you could also have a "show in new tab" option for the preview that uses all full semantics, kind of like your second bullet but not using an iframe.